# Slimphp 3 Nested Group Not working

Tags: php, slim

i have a little problem with slimphp router :

```
$app->group('/api', function () use ($app) {

    // Library group
    $this->group('/library', function () use ($app) {

        // Get book with ID
        $this->get('/books/:id', function ($req, $res) {
            echo "books";
        });

        // Update book with ID
        $this->put('/books/:id', function ($req, $res) {

        });

        // Delete book with ID
        $this->delete('/books/:id', function ($req, $res) {

        });

    });

});
```

Sending A `GET` to /api/library/books/1 give me a `Page not found` Error, where is the problem.

EDIT :

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

PS: a simple `app->get` is working without any problem,

Comment: Are you using slim 2 or slim 3? You seem to be mixing code from each.

Comment: i'm using slim 3

Comment: Can you add your webserver config (i.e. .htaccess)?

Comment: @meun5 its done.

Answer (score 1):

It is not found as Slim 3 uses `{id}` as placeholders, not `:id` as Slim 2 did. Therefore the code would be

```
$this->get('/books/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    ...
});
```

Found in [Slim 3 Documentation for Route Placeholders](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders)